# How would society change if everyone could spawn any living being?

Tags: magic, worldbuilding-process

How would society change if anyone could spawn any living being? This includes humans, animals, and even bacteria. By just thinking it, someone can make a lion appear. How would this go down/how would society continue?

Edit: When they spawn this animal, it will stay and act like a normal animal. This magic will start working now, with all the technology we have now.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding! Unfortunately the nature of questions "how would the world change" are too broad as a rule. There's too many variables to account for. Social, cultural, religion, economics, research done or not done and more. That is why I Vote To Close (VTC). Please don't hesitate to ask further questions or edit this one to glhave a smaller scope. Also check out the [tour] and the [help] if you want to learn more.

Comment: I appreciate the kind feedback. i will edit it rn

Comment: Coupd you make it even more focused? Like from what moment does it appear, what technology is available, would the creatures disappear or whatever?

Comment: @Trioxidane as you wish

Comment: Ow. A neighbor broke up with their girlfriend/boyfriend last week. One of the spawned a massive beehive. They're both dead now, but the bees are still *everywhere*.

Comment: A quick guess: people would design massive generators at high elevation, then spawn heavy/lots of animals to drive the power generation. At the bottom you turn it into food. "Living being" might be a bit too broad for what you want, as you focus on animals but you could easily create plants as well. This would revolutionize the world as farmland is no longer necessary (or at least for livestock) and both food+space become widely available. Economically much will be in a state of chaos for a while as entire industries dry up or appear, think spidersilk farming for example or chickens for eggs.

Comment: Just one annoyed 10 year old has to bring Galactus (or something worse) into being and we're done for ([Marvel universe](https://www.cbr.com/largest-marvel-comics-characters/)).

Comment: Hello Yosef. From the [help] we read that you shouldn't ask questions that are open-ended or too broad. We call this kind of question a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) which are a poor fit for the site. SE's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. If you can't imagine a single, best answer (I can't for this question), then you've not properly focused on a single, objective problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Society will collapse**

However you slice it, Society will collapse. We can compare it to the [mice utopia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_sink). We can spawn food in any form we like, but also fuel. Many bacteria can conceivably be used as such. We don't need to go out to survive anymore. This is where it'll start to collapse.

Our current Society has some failsafe against this. Currently we do have enough food to serve the world several times over. Economics and waste cause a part to still get hungry. The failsafe is all us need to work to get our food on the table and heat in our home, as well as some technological comforts. However, we do see a part of the mice utopia throughout mostly the western world. Although I cannot speak of cannibalism, we do see people getting sexual deviations, only focusing on being pretty, stopping with reproduction or parenting duties and antisocial behaviour. Although this isn't fully because of our abundance, the truth is that we have enough time and resources to expand on these nonstandard behaviours.

With spawning any living creatures by willful thought, you've given us the ability to both sustain and destroy us.

As in the intro, we will have an abundance of resources. Meat from even extinct creatures is available. We can repopulate the world with these creatures and might even bring back little Timmy from the dead. How wonderful.

But what does life matter then? If you can bring Timmy back from the dead, why not two?

I can imagine bringing little Timmy back is a step to far. Maybe you can just get "generic human child" or the like. So how long until hormonal teenagers start spawning naked humans to try to copulate with? Or maybe don't realise the danger of spawning a cool tiger? What will happen with their view of life if you can have animals or humans fight each other to the death, as you can always spawn more?

The abundance will already make us go crazy from the crazy possibilities that let us go far from our normal behaviours that protected us. Abundance and possibilities will kill us.

But what will happen if someone will start something dangerous? All the creatures spawned, or even humans, might get too much. Maybe they think of some nice ebola and other plagues to clean it up. Maybe someone doesn't like someone else and gives out a brain parasite? It takes only a few thoughts before someone thinks of the horrible diseases that are locked up at disease research labs around the world. Flu viruses that are a thousand times more contagious practically always deadly.

After 99% of the world is dead, will we spawn more humans to fill the gap again? Socially, it's just a big ruin.

There's a lot more perspectives to still look at, but in general it's too much abundance and power for people to have.

Comment: While I don't agree with all your points, I do agree that the result will be utter chaos, if not total destruction of all life on the planet. +1

Comment: @Demigan please don't call me dog. I fixed the link though :)

Comment: @YosefZaghi as Demigan says, we often ask for at least 24h of waiting to choose the answer. This is to give others a chance to answer the question, possibly giving deeper insights, better answers or opposing statements.

Comment: As for diseases, I think people might be too afraid of getting sick themselves. Spawning a Hippo next to your target though? Unlike a Tiger a Hippo does not need to be hungry to eviscerate and crush a human standing too close. Ofcourse this would naturally mean people might try to protect themselves in an escalating series of events: you spawn a hippo? Spawn something that might prey on the Hippo or fight it, like an Elephant or a swarm of hungry locusts. Without control over that someone else might spawn something, and then they spawn something against that... it gets busy real quick.

Comment: Your link isn't working triple oxygen. Also for the Yosef: it is customary to wait for 24 hours before accepting an answer. That way potentially more people can give an answer that might be better, but people might be discouraged if one answer is already accepted.

Comment: Why did you vote to close and also answered the question?

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica I forgot to retract it after the person changed the question. I deemed it just enough to answer with this.